# how to replace &,<,> in javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery

In javascript how it's possible to replace all occurrence of &,<,> in a string

I tried this

```
 var str="<>&";
 str.replace("&","&amp").replace("<","&lt").replace(">","&gt");
```

but not able to change even first occurrence

Comment: String string is a syntax error. Is this Java?

Comment: replace returns the string so you need to use that variable which is returned by replace...and also this is not javascript

Comment: my bad corrected it

Comment: Usually you can replace all occurrences with Regex replace.

Answer (score -1):

The easiest would be to use a regular expression with g flag to replace all instances:

```
str.replace(/foo/g, "bar")
```

This will replace all occurrences of foo with bar in the string str. If you just have a string, you can convert it to a RegExp object like this:

```
var pattern = "foobar",
re = new RegExp(pattern, "g");
```